# Can't execute python script through java while using websocket

Tags: java, android, python

I'm trying to control my raspberry pi using an android app. I'm using websocket to do this. As a test, I only want to send an output message from app (client) to host (pi) that will execute a python script. I can't get the python script to execute.
here's my codes:

host.java

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class host{
public static void main(String args[]){

    try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4141)) {

        System.out.println("I'm listening on port: " +serverSocket.getLocalPort());

        while (true) {



            try {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                String in = "";
                while ((in = input.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println("Message Received: " + in);
                    if(in.equals("test")){
                        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test.py");

                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            } 
        }    

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }   
}
```

}

here's my code for the android app:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String add = "192.168.100.7";
int port = 4141;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button test = (Button)findViewById(R.id.test);

    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            test();
        }
    });



private void test() {
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket(add, port);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        output.write("test");
        socket.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

There's no system output after message "I'm listening on port:".

Answer (score 0):

The client is not sending the message to the server/host process. This is because a `PrintWriter` with `autoFlush` enabled only flushes the output stream when one of the `println`, `printf`, or `format` methods is called. This excludes the `write` method. See [`PrintWriter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

Another option is to explicitly flush the output by calling the `flush` method after `write`, or by closing the output stream before closing the socket:

```
private void test() {
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket(add, port);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        output.write("test");
        output.flush();    # or output.close();
        socket.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You might want to add some more debug messages to your host code; firstly to ensure that the client is actually connecting to the server, to display the incoming messages, and to check the result of the sub process.